# Can we achieve SSO between 2 different login journeys which connect to 2 different Identity Stores in adb2c?

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure Active Directory Business to Consumer(adb2c).
We have designed custom policies, part of Identity Experience Framework(IEF) of Azure for  2 different applications.
One application is using login policy/flow which connects to a 3rd party Identity store.
Another application is using login policy/flow which connects to a different 3rd party Identity store.
Can we achieve SSO between them?

I am trying to use DefaultSSOSessionProvider session provider to skip technical profile which actually connect to 3rd party IDP and complete the login in case of SSO scenario. Getting exceptions while doing this.

Will this be possible or is there any other approach to achieve SSO?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable SSO for different applications in Azure AD B2C you need to [configure SSO at the tenant level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior). To be able to skip external IdP selection you need to set a TP that leverages the [ExternalLoginSSOSessionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso#externalloginssosessionprovider) in the UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement attribute of your external IdP TP. Take a look to the following [custom policy permalink](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/29424bc7a580c1ac8466d1200d14b8d37a7e8fff/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L545) for a sample.

Finally, the external IdP SSO is controlled by the IdP itself and not by B2C so if some problem arises ensure the IdP SSO is working before validating B2C SSO.